Cat6 pairs inner wires
I bought two 50 meter long cat6 cables. On the first one, each of inner wires of the pairs, was actually solid one wire while on the other it was like multiple hairs put together. Can someone give me more information on this? Also, is one better than the other? Is there a way to identify which is which without cutting the cable? Also, could a cat6 have split hairs for inner wires?
Thanks.

Certified Cat 6 should handle the signal the same, whether stranded or solid.
In use, there are some mechanical differences.

Stranded is best for a portion of cable outside the wall, such as going to a PC or router, which are likely to be moved. Solid conductor is better used inside walls and other places where it will not be frequently flexed.
For some connectors, it might be easier to use a solid conductor... or  not. A crimping tool might also be a bit easier to use on solid.

Practically speaking, there's not much difference. However, do check the temperature rating for cable inside a wall to see that it meets your locale's standards.

Thank you for the info. I am planning to use the cable to connect my router with the box outside the building using the cable. I got a DSL connection. Is there much difference? Note that the cable is exposed to heat and rain. Really hot temperature. Also, how do I know which is which by looking at the box containing the cable without cutting the cable? Here is the information of relevance on box containing cable with stranded wire. Part number: SM 702. Conductor (AWG): 24AWG. Nom O. D. (mm) 6.0.

Temp rating is often stamped on the outside of the wire, on insulation. Since it's not inside a wall, that rating might not be relevant. However, if being run outside, consider lightning protection at each end. Even a hot, dry wind such as Khamsin, can induce static discharges. Also consider a covering to protect cable if not specifically rated for outdoor use: https://www.cables.com/cablesblog/Cablescom/what-ethernet-cable-is-good-for-outdoor-use.html

A standard called TIA-568 defines Cat 6 and the other categories of cabling used by Ethernet and other telecommunications technologies. TIA-568 specifies that the bulk of the cable run between the switch and the device be done via solid-conductor cables ("in the walls", between the patch panel and the wall jack), but it allows for stranded-conductor "cords" of up to 5m to be used at each end of the run. So like a "patch cord" of up to 5m that runs between the patch panel and the switch, or a "work area cord" of up to 5m that runs between the wall jack and the PC.
A 50m long "cord" (stranded conductors, male plugs on both ends), does not comply with the TIA-568 standard.

That said, for home use, longer runs of stranded cable are probably acceptable, though not compliant.

@DrMoishePippik That all hinges on everyone agreeing on what "acceptable" means, which is why we have standards, so we can all point to "fully standards compliant" as basic acceptability criteria.
